# JSONP parsing in javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, web-scraping, jsonp

If I have an string containing a JSONP response, for example`"jsonp([1,2,3])"`, and I want to retrieve the 3rd parameter `3`, how could I write a function that do that for me? I want to avoid using `eval`. My code (below) works fine on the debug line, but return `undefined` for some reason.

```
  function unwrap(jsonp) {
    function unwrapper(param) {
      console.log(param[2]); // This works!
      return param[2];
    }
    var f = new Function("jsonp", jsonp);
    return f(unwrapper);
  }

  var j = 'jsonp([1,2,3]);'

  console.log(unwrap(j)); // Return undefined
```

More info: I'm running this in a node.js scraper, using `request` library.

Here's a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bortao/3nc967wd/

Comment: to answer why it returns undefined ... because `'jsonp([1,2,3]);'` should be `'return jsonp([1,2,3]);'` - you need to return values from functions if you want functions to return values

Comment: Further to what @JaromandaX said: `var f = new Function("jsonp", "return " + jsonp);`

Comment: either or @nnnnnn same result :p ahh, yes, but I know the difference - good pickup

Comment: Sure @JaromandaX, but I figured the `j` variable was standing in for the scraper utility so it would make sense to have the `return` part within the `unwrap()` and separate to that string.

Comment: yep, as I said, I see now how that makes more sense even though the end result is identical :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `slice` the string to remove the `jsonp(` and `);`, and then you can `JSON.parse` it:

```js
function unwrap(jsonp) {
  return JSON.parse(jsonp.slice(6, jsonp.length - 2));
}

var j = 'jsonp([1,2,3]);'

console.log(unwrap(j)); // returns the whole array
console.log(unwrap(j)[2]); // returns the third item in the array
```

Note that `new Function` is just as bad as `eval`.

Comment: but op was expecting `3` as the output :p

Answer (score 1):

Just a little changes and it'll work fine:

```
function unwrap(jsonp) {
    var f = new Function("jsonp", `return ${jsonp}`);
    console.log(f.toString())
    return f(unwrapper);
}

function unwrapper(param) {
    console.log(param[2]); // This works!
    return param[2];
}

var j = 'jsonp([1,2,3]);'
console.log(unwrap(j)); // Return undefined
```

without return your anonymous function is like this :

```
function anonymous(jsonp) {
    jsonp([1,2,3]);
}
```

because this function doesn't return so the output will be undefined.